Definition of $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^{(k)}$
In matrix algebra books such as Golub's Matrix Computations, the convergence of a sequence of matrices $(A^{(k)})$ to a matrix $A$ is defined when $\lim_{k \to \infty} \| A^{(k)} - A \| = 0$.
However, I believe this is not just a convention and there is a formal proof behind it, while I don't understand why it's not stated as a theorem. So is this reasoning correct for this statement?
In a metric space with matrix norm $\| . \|$ defined as the metric, convergence of $(A^{(k)})$ to a matrix $A$ is defined as follows:
For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\| A^{(k)} - A \| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. So $| \| A^{(k)} - A \| - 0 | < \epsilon$ and hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} \| A^{(k)} - A \| = 0$. The converse is also obtained in the same way.
Also, there is another way that limits of matrices are defined, which is entry-wise convergence. Are these definitions equivalent and are there any theorems to relate them to each other?

I am not a expert in this and currently going through things myself but this is my understanding :
first we define convergence as you have written. Then there is a theorem which says that in finite dimensional vector spaces, norms are equivalent that is if you show convergence in one of the norm, then it converges in any other norm (only true for finite dimensions). By using this, we can argue element wise convergence happens if it converges in any one of the norm.

Most, if not all, matrix norms are equivalent to each other. So if a sequence of matrices converges with respect to one norm, it does so with respect to another.

I think you know how norm in matrix is defined already....
so now here is the trick...assume the matrix does not converge entry wise, so now there exists a subsequence of matrices where atleast one of the i_j th entries is greater than say epsilon. Now multiply it by the following column vector (0,0,...1,0,0,...0) where we have 1 in the jth row. now clearly the norm of the matrix must be greater than epsilon.

If you are working over a complete normed field $\mathbb{F}$ such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ then any finite dimensional vector space can be given a norm which makes it complete and any two are equivalent (i.e., generate the same topology); this is a theorem that you can find in books. In particular you can see that whatever norm you take if you choose a basis you can make it isomorphic to some $\mathbb{F}^n$ and this can be made into a homeomorphism. The standard norm on $\mathbb{F}^n$ is of course $|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\cdots+|x_n|^2}$ and convergence is equivalent to convergence coordinate-wise.
Now the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices is a vector space of dimension $n^2$ and it can be given a norm. Since they are all equivalent it doesn't matter which. You could use the one above, but it is common to use the operator or sup norm.
All of this is standard and can be fund in books on basic linear algebra, especially ones covering numerical aspects.
